# Google Maps Directions API - Distance travelled in city and outside city

Tags: google-maps

So the user gives me two starting points A and B. I am able to calculate the total driving distance between those points but i am interested if its possible to get the distance traveled inside a city and outside city.

What i want to find out is the fuel consumption and i have two consumption values. One value is while you drive inside a city and one value while you travel outside. So less traffic, national roads, highways etc.

For example fuel consumption values:

```
city - 9l/100km
outside - 7l/100km
```

Distance between A and B

```
10km inside city
50km outside city
```

Fuel consumption:

```
9/100 * 10 + 7/100 * 50
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this automatically by implementing any APIs provided by Google. However, there are some manual ways. You have to make a database of the city boundary:

This [link](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org) returns a detail of a city. Like, if you search 'New York' the boundary of New York will be shown, like this:

[image]

Now if you click the detail button, you will get an OSM id which is '175905' for New York.

Now you have to go to [this link](http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/index.py) and paste this OSM in the `Id of relation` text box and submit. You will get polyline informations in many formats. Like New York - you have to save the polyline info for each city you want to include in your app.

Now the task becomes easy:

Add this into your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
}
```

and check if your current location falls under the any of the Polygon from your Database of cities:

`PolyUtil.containsLocation(yourLocation, cityPolyPointsList, false);`